# Roman numerals for only specific sections

Tags: numbering, overleaf, roman

I try to only number specific sections of my paper using Roman numerals. Basically, I attempt to have my main body numbered in Arabic numbers and the list of tables, figures as well as the appendix in Roman numerals.

With the following command I get the whole document in Roman numbers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\section{Main Body}

\section*{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: That is a very normal setup. So normal that many document classes have support for it via `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. After `\frontmatter` page numbering goes in lower case roman (as is tradition) and when `\mainmatter` appears, page numbering resets to normal arabic numbering and starts over from 1. Since you have not given any information about your setup, we cannot say if you can use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Is there enough information on my setup in the edited question?

Comment: Hmm, I may have misunderstood your question. Why don't your just use `\appendix` and make the redefinitions after `\appendix`. If placed in the preamble they are active everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't clarified it enough precisely. I mean the number of the titles/sections and not the page numbers. So I want to add Roman numbers in front of the titles (list of tables, figures, and appendix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still a bit confused as to what you want regarding the Appendix. Why not call it as `\section{Appendix}` instead of `\section*{Appendix}`?

Use the `tocloft` package to change the LoF and Lot titles.

```
% Romanprob.tex  SE 615700

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

%% change the LoF and LoT titles to \section style
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
%%%%\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{\section{\contentsname}}
\renewcommand{\@cftmakeloftitle}{\section{\listfigurename}}
\renewcommand{\@cftmakelottitle}{\section{\listtablename}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%%%%\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\section{Main Body}

\section*{Appendix}  %% unnumbered Appendix
\section{Appendix}   %% numbered Appendix

\end{document}
```

[image]